# Classes using methods of other dependencies is not working in my custom library, any suggestions?

Tags: android

I have created by own library for helper methods & classes also included few other dependencies, then used the jitpack to create a custom dependency. But after implementing it to a project, the classes using the other dependencies are not visible to android studio.

I tried adding the other specific dependencies to the project and it works but I need to find alternative way without the need of adding specific dependencies. If it is possible, please do help.

My Library: [My-Utility](https://github.com/atu09/My-Utility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

If you are expecting any of those `implementation` dependencies to be automatically visible to apps using your library, replace `implementation` with `api`.

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations) for more.